# How to copy a HTML collection to an array in JS

Tags: javascript, web-deployment

I want to save the color of all my buttons in a Webpage in an array and change the color of my buttons. Later I want to be able to access that colors and turn it back again. This is my HTML code

```js
var all_buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
var copyAllButtons = [];

for (let i = 0; i < all_buttons.length; i++) {
  copyAllButtons.push(all_buttons[i]);
}

function buttonColorChange(buttonThis) {

  if (buttonThis.value === 'red') {
    buttonsRed();
  } else if (buttonThis.value === 'reset') {
    buttonColorReset();
  }
}

function buttonsRed() {
  for (let i = 0; i < all_buttons.length; i++) {
    all_buttons[i].classList.remove(all_buttons[i].classList[1]);
    all_buttons[i].classList.add('btn-danger');
  }
}

function buttonColorReset() {
  for (let i = 0; i < all_buttons.length; i++) {
    console.log(typeof(all_buttons));
    all_buttons[i].classList.remove(all_buttons[i].classList[1]);
    console.log(copyAllButtons[0].classList);
    all_buttons[i].classList.add(copyAllButtons[i]);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="flex-box-pick-color">
  <form action="">
    <select name="backdrop" id="background" onchange="buttonColorChange(this)">
      <option value="random">Random</option>
      <option value="red">Red</option>
      <option value="reset">Reset</option>
    </select>
  </form>
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Whatever</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger">Nothing</button>
  <button class="btn btn-warning">:)</button>
  <button class="btn btn-success">(:</button>
</div>
```

So I have this dropdown, and if you select red, all the buttons on the page become red. But if you select reset, it must change the colors back. Currently, the copyAllButtons variable is also changing when the all_buttons variable changes, so then it gives me the error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'add' on 'DOMTokenList': The
> token provided ('[object HTMLButtonElement]') contains HTML space
> characters, which are not valid in tokens.

What can I do?

Comment: What value is it trying to add?

Comment: `arr = Array.from(HTMLCollection);`.

Comment: The error is quite clear. `copyAllButtons` contains DOM nodes (here `HTMLButtonElement`s). What do you expect `all_buttons[i].classList.add(<HTMLButtonElement>)` to do?

Comment: @Andreas I want to change the colors back with that

Comment: @Teemu I already tried that

Comment: `.add()` expects a string and not a DOM node. How should this work?

Comment: Where must I use that? Can you give me some code pls?

Answer (score 0):

You access DOM node, not the actual class. Your buttonColorReset function should be like this:

```
function buttonColorReset() {
  for (let i = 0; i < all_buttons.length; i++) {
    console.log(typeof(all_buttons));
    all_buttons[i].classList.remove(all_buttons[i].classList[1]);
    console.log(copyAllButtons[0].classList);
    all_buttons[i].classList.add(copyAllButtons[i].className)
  }
}
```

Comment: This line: "all_buttons[i].classList.remove(all_buttons[i].classList[1]);" effects the copyAllButtons variable two so it does'nt have a color.

Comment: so just toggle classList: "all_buttons[i].classList.toggle(copyAllButtons[i].className);" instead of removing class and delete line with add method

Comment: function buttonColorReset() {
  for (let i = 0; i < all_buttons.length; i++) {
    console.log(typeof(all_buttons));
    all_buttons[i].classList.toggle(copyAllButtons[i].className)
  }
}

Comment: I get this error now: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'toggle' on 'DOMTokenList': The token provided ('btn btn-primary') contains HTML space characters, which are not valid in tokens